# YACC: Stop parsing specific path

Tags: parsing, yacc, ply

I'm using Python PLY to parse a specific language. For a grammar like:

```
IF LPAREN condition RPAREN LBRACE stmtlist RBRACE ELSE LBRACE stmtlist RBRACE
```

When I know the `condition` value, say True, then is there a way to stop parsing the `stmtlist` in the `ELSE` path?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to continue the parse, because you need to find the end of the block enclosed by the second `RBRACE`; in other words, you need to parse to find the beginning of the next statement.

That said, when you *analyze the results* of the parse (to generate code, construct an AST, whatever you need to do), if you can determine that `condition` always evaluates to `true` (perhaps it is the expression `1 = 1`), then you can suppress generating code for the second `stmtlist`.

**Update:**

Your grammar (the *syntax* of your language) is specified non-procedurally, so there's no place for you to attach conditional logic.

On the other hand, you specify *semantic* actions to take when a particular syntactic element of your grammar is matched, and you do this procedurally.  In [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn23), you do this by coding the body of grammar rule function(s).  In the grammar rule function that matches the second `stmtlist`, you can write conditional code to skip over code generation, based on other information you have figured out about the input program (the input to your compiled language processor).

Comment: but how can we suppress it? I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: It might help if you were to show your complete `yacc.py` file.

Comment: Hi David, I pasted the yacc here http://pastebin.com/wRnuNaWD. I use the `names` dictionary to store all the variable values in the parsing procedure. When the parsing reaches the `ifelse` path, I may know the `condition` value (`coreopnd` in my code). However, I think because of my data structure I give myself a hard problem when I want to ignore the `if` or `else` _semantic_ path. Do you have any suggestion?